# Как "отловить" нужный URI, переданный в WebView?

Tags: android, java

При помощи Контент Провайдера в `WebView` загружается страница с параметрами

```
  mWebView.loadUrl("content://com.example/TList2.htm?Status=Good");
```

Затем в самой HTML странице при помощи Контент Провайдера подгружаются скрипты, картинки.

Вопрос в следующем: как в страничке можно перехватить вызвавший ее URI? 
Вот этот:

```
  content://com.example/TList2.htm?Status=Good
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = document.location.href;
```